# How to Retrive the data from array of objects (JQuery available)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to retrieve the data from below array.
How to retrieve data by categorie wise.
how to retrieve only key values 
how to retrieve only data values

```
var main = [{
   "key": "all",
   "data": ['img/icon1.png', 'img/icon2.png', 'img/icon3.png']
}, {
   "key": "cat1",
   "data": ['img/icon1.png', 'img/icon2.png', 'img/icon3.png']
}, {
   "key": "cat2",
   "data": ['img/icon1.png', 'img/icon2.png']
}, {
   "key": "cat3",
   "data": ['']
}, {
   "key": "cat4",
   "data": ['']
}, {
   "key": "cat5",
   "data": ['img/icon1.png']
}];
```

Comment: This might help you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: That won't help. The OP does not have JSON, he has a JavaScript array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function:

```
var category = 'cat2';

var result = $.grep(main, function() {
    return this.key === category;
});

if (result.length > 0) {
    // We have found an element in the array that satisfies the condition
    // => we could access it's data property:
    var data = result[0].data; // this will equal to ['img/icon1.png', 'img/icon2.png']
}
```

As an alternative to using jQuery, you could use the native javascript [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to achieve the same goal:

```
var result = main.filter(function(element) {
    return element.key === category;
});

if (result.length > 0) {
    // We have found an element in the array that satisfies the condition
    // => we could access it's data property:
    var data = result[0].data; // this will equal to ['img/icon1.png', 'img/icon2.png']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help you!

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/2XJNt/

```
alert(main[0].data);
```

or if you want to loop through your main variable

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/2XJNt/1/

```
for (var i=0;i<main.length;i++)
{
    alert(main[i].data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ if the JSON data is coming from an API or file somewhere.

Otherwise just access the object properties as such: `main[0].key` or `main[1].data`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WmEbU/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain JavaScript to reorganize your data, like this:

```
var flat_data = [];
var all_keys = []
var data_by_cat = {};

for (var i = 0; i < main.length; ++i) {

   var item = main[i];

   // check if you already saved that key
   if (all_keys.indexOf(item['key']) == -1) {

      all_keys.push(item['key']);

      // you also need to add a new key to data_by_cat
      data_by_cat[item['key']] = [];

   }

   // append all data to flat_data and data_by_cat
   for (var j = 0; j < item['data'].length; ++j) {

      flat_data.push(item['data'][j]);
      data_by_cat[item['key']].push(item['data'][j]);

   }

}
```

Then you get all your `data` elements in `flat_data`, the list of the keys in `all_keys` and a dictionary having your keys as keys and an array of all your data per cateogory as a values, like this:

```
var flat_data = [
    "img/icon1.png",
    "img/icon2.png",
    "img/icon3.png",
    "img/icon1.png",
    "img/icon2.png",
    "img/icon3.png",
    "img/icon1.png",
    "img/icon2.png",
    "",
    "",
    "img/icon1.png"
    ];

var all_keys = [
    "all",
    "cat1",
    "cat2",
    "cat3",
    "cat4",
    "cat5"
    ];

var data_by_cat = {
    "all": [
        "img/icon1.png",
        "img/icon2.png",
        "img/icon3.png"
        ],
    "cat1": [
        "img/icon1.png",
        "img/icon2.png",
        "img/icon3.png"
        ],
    "cat2": [
        "img/icon1.png",
        "img/icon2.png"
        ],
    "cat3": [
        ""
        ],
    "cat4": [
        ""
        ],
    "cat5": [
        "img/icon1.png"
        ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you got the JSON stored in an object. Now that object is a pure Javascript array. So iterate over it and get you values.

```
for(var i=0;i<main.length;i++){
    alert('Key['.concat(i).concat('] =').concat(main[i].key));
    alert('data['.concat(i).concat('] =').concat(main[i].data));
}
```

My solution to your example as a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hunkyhari/grttY/1/

Answer (score 0):

the data you want is already "retrieved" from json, since it is in the code itself, assigned to a variable, the interpreter already has the array

as for the rest of the questions: (non jquery solution)

to retrieve only "keys" (the `element.key` values of each element in the array):

`main.map(function (a) {return a.key})`

to retrieve only data:

`main.map(function (a) {return a.data})`

and to retrieve by category:

`main.filter(function(a){return a.key===category})[0]`

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/cbs8C/)